# Listener registered within an IntentService receives notification only once

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice

I am writing a simple app to keep track of the periods when my phone has poor signal strength. I do this using an `IntentService`, which listens for `PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS` as follows:

```
public class PoorSignalIntentService extends IntentService {

    private TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager;
    private PhoneStateListener mPhoneStateListener;
    public PoorSignalIntentService() {
        super("PoorSignalIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        mPhoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
                doSomething(signalStrength);
                super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState) {
                doSomething(serviceState);
                super.onServiceStateChanged(serviceState);
            }
        };

        mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        mTelephonyManager.listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS|PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);

    }

    private void doSomething(SignalStrength signalStrength){
        Log.d(TAG, "Signal Strength changed! New strength = "+signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength());
    }

    private void doSomething(ServiceState serviceState){
        Log.d(TAG, "Service State changed! New state = "+serviceState.getState());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Shutting down the IntentService");
        mTelephonyManager.listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

However, I see that after the first signal strength changed notification is received, the `onDestroy()` is called (presumably, the `IntentService` calls `stopSelf()`).

This problem is not limited to `PhoneStateListener`. I have another simple app which uses the Proximity Sensor thus:

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
```

In this case too, only the first proximity change was notified, after which the `Service` stopped itself.

So, what is the pattern for registering listeners like these in a `Service`?

Comment: Any inputs? I'll be happy to provide any additional info ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. My bad. I should be using a `Service` rather than `IntentService`, since the latter calls `stopSelf()` after processing the intents it receives in `onHandleIntent()`.

Here's the working code which extends `Service`:

```
public class PoorSignalService extends Service {

    private TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager;
    private PhoneStateListener mPhoneStateListener;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // We don't want to bind; return null.
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        mPhoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
                doSomething(signalStrength);
                super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState) {
                doSomething(serviceState);
                super.onServiceStateChanged(serviceState);
            }
        };
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //Register the listener here.
        mTelephonyManager.listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS|PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    private void doSomething(SignalStrength signalStrength){
        Log.d(TAG, "Signal Strength changed! New strength = "+signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength());
    }

    private void doSomething(ServiceState serviceState){
        Log.d(TAG, "Service State changed! New state = "+serviceState.getState());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Shutting down the Service");
        mTelephonyManager.listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```