# CANNOT get PhoneStateListener to work. I've seen the examples

Tags: android

I need an application wide listener to determine when the service state changes on the phone. I've been through every example online, copied line for line, modified the manifest, and I CANNOT get anything to work.

Does a phone state listener HAVE to been in activity? Can I have some plain old class to listen for a phone state change??

This is very frustrating.

In my class I have...

```
     private class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(android.content.Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.i(TAG, "onReceive");

            MyPhoneStateListener qpsl = new myPhoneStateListener();
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            tm.listen(qpsl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);
        }
    }

    private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener{

public void onServiceStateStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState){
    Log.i(TAG, "ServiceState = " + serviceState.getState();
}
```

I know I need to modify the manifest for the broadcast receiver and phonestate. Where? I want this application wide.

This is all the code I have, can someone show me what I'm missing so that I can listen for a service state change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the reason nothing works for you is the broadcast is never received. What broadcast have you registered in manifest? Remember, phone state change is not a "traditional" broadcast. You need to register this `PhoneStateListener` object instead.

In any case, you don't need a `BroadcastReceiver` for this. Just use a `Service` instead. Just move the code from `onReceive()` above into `onStartCommand()` of a `Service` and you should be good to go.

I have implemented something along similar lines in a simple "Poor Signal History" app and it works fine. The project is uploaded [here](http://code.google.com/p/poor-signal-history/source/checkout).

Comment: What should I put in the manifest to make this work? How do I register the receiver?

Comment: Like I said, since phone state is not a traditional `Broadcast`. Had it been one, you'd have to register it in manifest and mention what's the broadcast intent your `BroadcastReceiver` is interested in. The correct way to "register" a phone state listener is to use the `TelephonyManager`'s `listen()` method, which you are already doing. Now all you need to do is move this code out of the `onReceive()` since it is never called. Check this answer on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8657099/570930